# Tabla de compras: cantidad comprada sea igual a existencias de la tabla producto

Tags: sql

Este es el Trigger. Al momento de ejecutarlo me actuliza toda la tabla de producto poniendo la misma compra en todos los productos.

```
delimiter 
create trigger actualizarPrecioProducto
before update on compras
for each row
begin if new.cantidadc <> OLD.cantidadc
then
update producto
set producto.existencias = new.cantidadc;
end if;
end;
```

Lo llamo

```
update compras set cantidadc=6 where idcompras=1 ;
```

Atributos de las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es PostgreSQL? ¿MySQL? ¿SQL Server? Ponlo en las etiquetas. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te actualiza la existencia de todos los productos(ERROR)

```
update producto
set producto.existencias = new.cantidadc;
```

tienes que ponerle un filtro con identificador del producto que estas comprando(posible solución):

```
update producto
set producto.existencias = new.cantidadc where idProducto=OLD.producto_idProducto;
```

Posible solución porque no se muy bien que quieres hacer, pero por lo menos no te vas a carga todas las existencias.

Esto solo funciona si tienes una sola compra por producto que no es lo habitual!!!O solo compras cuando se acaban las existencias que tampoco es habitual!!

**Esto es lo que se hace habitualmente:**

```
update producto
        set producto.existencias =
            producto.existencias+ new.cantidadc - OLD.cantidadc 
where idProducto=OLD.producto_idProducto;
```

Por ejemplo, para corregir un error cuando se introdujeron las cantidades en la compra---etc

Comment: tengo que hacer un trigger en donde si pongo en la tabla de compras en la columna de cantidadc=8 esa cantidad se actualice en la tabla de producto y se le sume a las existencias=10+8 existencias 18

Comment: Y que pasa si antes tenia un valor 6(en cantidadc) por ejemplo no tendrias que sumar solo 2. existencias=(10+8-6)

Comment: ahi no pasa nada por que solo son datos de entrada